# Make close button hide instead of closing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I make the close button on a form effectively act as a 'Hide' button?

Is there a way to abort the `FormClosing` event?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just capture the `FormClosing` event and stop the default action, then instead of closing the form just hide it:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be pretty straight forward:

> To cancel the closure of a form, set the `Cancel` property of the `FormClosingEventArgs` passed to your event handler to `true`.

Concerning part two of the question with hiding the window, hide to taskbar or hide to notification area?